# One cron expression for multiple AWS regions

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron

I want to schedule an AWS Lambda to be triggered at 02:00 AM localtime everyday in multiple AWS regions. Is there a way to define a cron expression that will invoke the lambda in such a way?

Ex: For these regions - ap-northeast-1(Tokyo), ap-south-1(Mumbai) and us-east-1(N.Virginia) the lambda should be invoked at 02:00AM local time of their respective regions.

So, lambda in Tokyo (UTC+9) will be triggered first, followed by Mumbai(UTC+5:30) and N.Virginia(UTC-4) regions.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create one EventBridge rule for each region, and then you will have to use [cross-region event routing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-cross-region-event-routing-with-amazon-eventbridge)  to invoke the lambda.